# Is the value for the Boltzmann Constant different in 2D?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, physical-constants, gas

So I'm simulating some hard sphere collisions and want to determine the Boltzmann constant in two dimension, using the equation
$$PA=Nk_BT$$
where $A=\pi R^2_{\text{container}}$, $P=(\text{average Impulse}/\text{time})/(2\pi R_{\text{container}})$. $E_k=k_BT$(deg of freedom=2).
I'm plotting several graphs of $P$ against $T$ so that $$k_{B,2D}=\frac{A\cdot \text{Gradient}}{N}$$
but cannot get a consistent (constant) value for $k_{B,2D}$? In the sense that $k_{B,2D}$ keeps decreasing as I keep decreasing the radius of the molecules? Does this imply that no such a constant exists?

The spheres are too small to obey the VdW equation (at least 1000 times smaller than container)

Comment: Out of curiosity, which algorithm do you use for your simulation? How do you include the temperature $T$ in it? Do you draw the initial velocity and position randomly from a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution and let the system evolve?

Answer (score 1):

Without further information about your simulation (which would probably be more at home on [SciComp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com)), I can't say for sure what's going on.

However, to answer the title question the Boltzmann constant is just the proportionality constant which we use to convert temperature units to energy units. If we choose to measure temperature in units of energy and allow entropy to be dimensionless (the only sensible choice$^\dagger$), then it doesn't even appear. When it *does* appear, it has no relation to the dimensionality of the  physical space occupied by your thermodynamical system.

$^\dagger$This is (mostly) a joke.